# How can I distinguish an empty variable from a variable that has the value "0"?

Tags: php

I am a little confused with `empty` and `0`. I want to find out if `$number` is empty. This means for example `$number =`  But this should not include `0` because if `$number = 0` it is not empty for me.

```
$number = 0;

if(empty($number)){
echo "$number is empty.";
} else {
echo "$number is 0";
}
```

My result is `$number is empty`.

Comment: how about `$number = 0.00;`? It should be treated as `0` or empty?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: this is also not empty.

Comment: "this is also not empty" - I would change the message "$number is 0" to ""$number is not empty"" - if  `0` is not empty for you

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I wrote it for this question like this, to make clear, what I mean

Comment: @Jarla, I think you are now clear about the `empty` and `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/empty

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
```

Note that this is exactly the same list as for a coercion to Boolean false.

empty is simply !isset($var) || !$var. Try [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here your workaround issues you can check this way.

```
 $number = 0;
    if (empty($number) && $number!== '0') {
        echo "$number is empty.";
    } else {
    echo "$number is 0";
    }
```

here i have checked if it is empty and non zero value then it is empty. hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Firsly, use 
`echo "\$number is empty";`
or 
`echo '$number is empty'l`
because when you write "$number", you'll get a value of $number instead of string '$number'.

About your question.
In your example your $number has integer value 0.
It's equal to boolean false.

Write description section here:
[php.net empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Correct example:

```
$number = 0
if($number === 0)
    echo '$number is 0';
elseif(empty($number))
    echo '$number is empty';
else 
    echo '$number isn't empty and not equal to 0';
```